# Binding style attributes to component properties in polymer-1.0

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Given the following .html

### .html

```
<!-- shared-styles.html -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      .red { color: red; }
    </style> 
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

and the .dart src

### .dart

```
@property
String redColor = ...
```

How can I bind the redColor property to the color attribute in the  element of the .html declaration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported.

I would use the Polymer API to change CSS variables like shown in [polymer 1.0 - how to change font size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330007/polymer-1-0-how-to-change-font-size-programmatically) as work-around.